# Axion Release Plugin Error on Gradle Build

Tags: android, gradle, azure-devops, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I’ve been struggling to build an Android lib and publish it to Azure Devops Artifacts using Gradle.

I finally published it yesterday, and today I came across the need to version it automatically, so I’m trying to use this plugin:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release
https://axion-release-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

So, making it shorter, I’m simply not able to apply the plugin, I’m not even using it, just applied it, and it breaks instantly.

Any ideas on the reason?

I applied it based on this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "pl.allegro.tech.build:axion-release-plugin:1.11.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release" version '1.11.0'
```

The error I’m getting is this:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'core'.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'core'.
> Cannot invoke method version() on null object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it was the version info in the: 
`apply plugin: "pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release" version '1.11.0'`

Using: 
`apply plugin: "pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release"`

It works.